# Why is the learning rate of printed keras model unchanged？

Tags: keras, optimization

cdoe:

```
 def get_lr_metric(optimizer):
     def lr(y_true, y_pred):
         return optimizer.lr
     return lr
 optimizer = tensorflow.keras.optimizers.Adam()
 lr_metric = get_lr_metric(optimizer)
 Mymodel.compile(loss='mse',optimizer=optimizer,metrics=[lr_metric])
```

output:
Epoch 1/60
2/2 [==============================] - 1s 305ms/step - loss: 0.3573 - lr: 0.0010
Epoch 2/60
2/2 [==============================] - 1s 338ms/step - loss: 0.2773 - lr: 0.0010
Epoch 3/60
2/2 [==============================] - 1s 365ms/step - loss: 0.2464 - lr: 0.0010
This happens when I use the built-in optimizer (such as nadam, sgd...) and  lead to unstable training. When I use the LearningRateScheduler to rewrite the change of learning rate, the result of printing the learning rate is really changing and lead ti stable training.
so what happened?I'm confused.

Comment: Because Adam or SGD do not have variable learning rate.

Comment: But mine worked，so why ？